# Transformation matrices with 2 different bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I not really sure if I'm doing it right so I wanted to ask here:
I'm given a linear map $f:\Bbb{R^3} \rightarrow \Bbb{R^2} $ with $f((x,y,z)^T)= (x+y,y+z)^T$
and Bases $B=((1,-1,0)^T,(0,1,-1)^T,(1,1,1)^T)$ and $B'=((1,1)^T,(1,0)^T)$. I have to find the matrix of $f$ regarding the basis $B$ and $B'$

So I first wanted to know what f does to the standard basis of $\Bbb{R^3}$ and I got the Matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\\
    0 & 1 & 1 
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
So next thing is to find both base transformation matrices.

If I want to know how i get from the standard basis to the basis $B$ I simply have to right down the Vectors in a Matrix:

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\\
    -1 & 1 & 1 \\\
    0 & -1 & 1 
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

and the same goes for $B'$:
$$T=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1  \\\
    1 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

And then Multiply:

$$TAM=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1  \\\
    1 & 0  
    \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\\
    0 & 1 & 1 
    \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\\
    -1 & 1 & 1 \\\
    0 & -1 & 1 
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$=\begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 1 & 4 \\\
    0 & 1 & 2 
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Is that about right? I'm really unsure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, but almost. 
You have to take the *inverse* of $T$.

Nevertheless, you can verify your solution by calculating $Ab_i$ (which are just the columns of $AM$) and expressing them in basis $B'$.

(This last step is equivalent to multiplying by $T^{-1}$ from the left. Can you see why?)

Comment: not quite, $T$ gives me the transformation from the standard basis of $\Bbb{R^2=$ to $B'$, if I take the inverse would'nt that be the opposite of what I am trying to do?

Comment: If we are given the coordinates $(x,y)^T $ of a vector $v$, then it means $v=T\pmatrix{x\\y}$, which results in the standard coordinates of $v$. But now we're given the standard coordinates of $v=Ab_i$, and we are curious about the $B' $ coordinates $x,y$, for which we have $\pmatrix{x\\y} =T^{-1}v$.